# Do the Mid 2011 MacBook Air Support Jumbo Frames (via Thunderbolt + Display)

Tags: networking, macbook-air

Since the MBA is capable of significantly greater bandwidth when attached to the 27" Thunderbolt Display, I am wondering if it does, or it's possible to turn on Jumbo Frames?!

If so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: To prevent questions: [The 27" Thunderbolt display by Apple](http://www.apple.com/displays/specs.html) has an Ethernet port provided for computers connected to it.

Comment: There's no reason why it has to be jumbo frames -- the Thunderbolt interface is much faster than the USB interface, so you'd expect an Ethernet connection made via Thunderbolt to be faster than any other network connection to an MBA.

Comment: I apologise for not making the question clearer. The MBA WILL be connected via Thunderbolt to the Display; and a gigabit cable out the back of it. I then wish to know if it's possible to take advantage of jumbo frames to drive even further bandwidth that is possible with a default MTU size. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering one day. It is infact available when connecting the Thunderbolt Display to a MBA and a jumbo-frames-enabled network.

Although looking at the performance, doesn't seem to be the full 9000 bytes. Further testing is needed.